# Which [varien] object is required to successfully run getCompilerStatus()?

Tags: compiler, varien, object

I'm attempting to programmatically determine if Magento's compilation status is enabled or disabled. I found the function getCompilerStatus() in app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/compiler/process.phtml that allows you to determine the status in the admin panel. I am however trying to run this from a "workbench" script outside of the admin panel. Here is what I have:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);

# workebench script
require_once('app/Mage.php');
umask(0);
Mage::app();

echo "Checking Compilation Status<br />";

// Code that would work in admin panel
echo $this->getCompilerStatus();
```

The result: ***Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context***

So I Googled the function and came across the following link from Magento which shows the "Varien Objects" required: http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Compiler/Mage_Compiler_Block_Process.html#getCompilerStatus

From this it appears that I need to load Mage_Core_Block_Abstract, Mage_Core_Block_Template and I'm assuming I can drop Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template as my function does not require the admin panel.

Can anyone tell me if I'm going about this the right way? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually that method just checks if the constant COMPILER_INCLUE_PATH is defined.

The only place where this seems to be set is includes/config.php. So I've never used the compiler, but it looks like that this file is modified when the compiler is activated, so I would include it and after that check as in the method if the constant is defined.

Comment: Interesting. So you're saying that this isn't a database config entry that reflects the status of the compiler?

Comment: Correctly, just check the getCompilerStatus method.

Comment: Thank you! Can you provide a link or any advice on doing that? I'm relatively new to this process.